# git обновление локального репозитория

Tags: git, github, репозиторий, git-pull

есть два ПК (пк1 и пк2) в разных сетях, которые пушат в гитхаб обновы проекта.

**Проблема:** пк1 20-го числа запушил 4 новых каталога в проект с файлами. пк2 21 числа только установил гит, поэтому клонировал полностью репозиторий с гитхаб. Удалил 2 из 4-х каталогов, оставшиеся 2 переименовал, и добавил еще 2 новых каталога, затем запушил изменение. 22 числа пк1 нужно получить изменения, которые внес пк2. пк1 чуть меньше чем новичек в гит, поэтому он читает в инетах, что чтобы обновить свой локальный репозиторий (в соответствии с удаленным) ему нужно использовать git pull origin, что по сути - слияние. В итоге пк1 получает на свой локальный пк +4 новых каталога,из которых 2 - переименованные старые каталоги, которые уже лежат в локальном репозитории под старым названием, и 2 новых каталога от пк2. Каталоги, которые удалил пк2 все еще остаются в локальном репозитории пк1.

**Вопрос:** как обновлять свой локальный репозиторий **в полном** соответствии с удаленным? или, если угодно, превратить гит в google drive для кода?.

Единственное что приходит мне на ум - постоянное клонирование, но я больше чем уверен что это не грамотно.

Comment: Основы гита описаны в интернет в полной мере, основные команды git status, git commit -am "ТЕкст комита" , git pull origin ветка, git push origin ветка

Comment: а ну да еще git branch и git checkout ветка

Comment: странно, я постарался максимально детально описать проблему, из чего я надеялся что Вы, или кто-либо другой поймет, что я знаком с этими командами. На всякий случай скажу еще раз, что при git pull origin master в локальный репозиторий ДОБАВЛЯЮТСЯ новые файлы/каталоги, но при этом если в удаленном репозитории было что-то удалено, то из локального при git pull origin master это не удаляется. более того, каталоги не переименовываются. Т.е. если в уд. реп был переименован каталог, то он при git pull origin master добавится в локальный как новый.

Comment: ну вот допустим ситуация: до того как что-то менять, вы сняли мастер из удаленного репозитроия. Далее вы что-то изменили и скоммитили. Далее ваши действия должны быть следующими, вы тянете опять себе мастер через pull и после только шлете push таким образом если у вас кто-то еще что-то изменил вы получите либо обновления либо конфликты.

Comment: если же сделали не так, вы должны вернутся откатится к нужному заголовку, внести изменения и отправить все правильно.

Comment: алгоритм был такой: пк1->edit->git add . -> commit -> git push origin master; пк2->git clone->edit->git add . ->commit-> git push origin master;  пк1-> git pull origin master (от чего сыр-бор); сильно смущает тот факт. что на гитхабе репозиторий хранится в правильном виде, без лишних каталогов и с переименованием. Теперь после сливания git status вообще говорит, что все отлично, все актуальненько - при этом в локальном реп. находится 2 лишних каталога.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git отслеживает только файлы, но не каталоги, поэтому он не удаляет каталоги, которые стали пустыми в результате мержа или любого другого изменния. Если вас раздражают лишние пустые каталоги - их можно удалить вызовом `git clean -fd` (`-f` - принудительное удаление, `-d`- как неотслеживаемых файлов, так и каталогов).

Comment: Да, в итоге git clean -fd решил мой вопрос, но по сути это тоже самое если бы я руками удалил бы эти каталоги. Спасибо, узнал о гит чуть больше.

Answer (score 5):

Git оперирует файлами, а не папками. Поэтому когда **пк2** переименовывал папку, git отслеживал изменение путей к файлам, которые в ней содержались на момент переименования или даже, если хотите, перемещения файлов в другую папку.

Склонировав репозиторий 21го числа, **пк2** в своем локальном репозитории получил проект в состоянии, зафиксированном днем ранее **пк1**. Поработав с проектом **пк2** сделал push в тот же день, изменив состояние удаленно репозитория.

Похоже, что **пк1** в интервале между отправкой изменений в репозиторий 20 числа и попыткой синхронизации 22 числа совершил какие-то действия с файлами в "переименованных" папках, например добавил в каждую новый файл, и зафиксировал изменения.

Рассмотрим, следующую упрощенную модель: есть папка `./folder_a/` содержащая файл `file.1`. Добавляя эту папку под контроль версий, вы на самом деле "говорите" git следить за изменениями файла `file.1`. Когда вы переименовываете папку `./folder_a/` в `./folder_b/`, гит фиксирует изменения в пути к файлу `file.1` не следя при этом за тем что происходит с самой папкой `folder_a`. Теперь когда изменения зафиксированы и выполнен push в удаленный репозиторий, представим, что другой пользователь репозитория создал в папке `folder_a` локальной копии репозитория файлик `file.2` и зафиксировал изменения:

```
git add ./folder_a/file.2
git commit -m 'add file.2'
```

При обновлении синхронизации с удаленным репозиторием он получит файл `./folder_b/file.1` с его же файлом `./folder_a/file.2`, ожидаемо, ничего не произойдет. В итоге в проекте будут оба файла. При этом присутствуют и папки в которых они находятся: `./folder_a/` и `./folder_b/`.

> Если все же необходимо получить в локальном репозитории состояние удаленного, игнорируя при этом не зафиксированные изменения локального репозитория, можно выполнить следующие команды:
>
> ```
> git fetch
> git reset --hard origin/master
> ```

Comment: Спасибо за подробное описание, мои опасения подтвердились. Получается для гит каталог это всего лишь часть информации о файле - изменился каталог, не беда, создадим для отслеживаемого файла нужный. Я пробовал команды git fetch
git reset --hard origin/master - в итоге ничего не поменялось. В баше вывод: $ git reset --hard origin/master
HEAD is now at 710d625 тест. Все каталоги как старые так и новые на месте